How to workaround missing functionality in Camel SMB component
For some reason Camel SMB component doesn't implement file framework as other file related Camel components do. As a result significant part configuration properties (such as move, include, exclude, maxMessagesPerPoll, sortBy, moveFailed, fileName, tempFileName etc.) are not available for SMB consumer and producer. Some configs that are available in ftp component (like stepwise, streamDownload etc.) are not present in SMB component.
Is there any convenient way to add missing functionality other than create a custom SMB component that implements Camel file framework?

There is no way to do that. The SMB was created with some basic needs and we do not have endless resources to create everything for free forever. So if you are in need of this, then you can maybe help improve the camel-smb to sit on top of camel-file like camel-ftp does and then have a lot more features out of the box.
https://camel.apache.org/community/contributing/

Thank you for the response, Claus. I considered contributing, but I was not sure if Camel file framework from camel-file was not used in camel-smb intentionally because of some special reasons. Now it is clear that implementing file framework in camel-smb won't contradict the original plans for camel-smb.

I created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-21352
